# Ant hostname works on command line, but not in Jenkins

Tags: ant, jenkins

I have an Ant script with the following to determine the hostname (windows or unix):

```
<condition property="hostname" value="${env.COMPUTERNAME}" else="${env.HOSTNAME}">
    <os family="windows" />
</condition>
```

Later on I echo this out:

```
<echo message="${hostname}" />
```

If I run this on the command line it outputs the hostname correctly:

```
[echo] sample.hostname.com
```

If I run this through Jenkins on a Linux slave I get the following:

```
[echo] ${env.HOSTNAME}
```

Anyone know of why this works on command line and not on Jenkins?

Thanks!

Comment: This is infuriating that a Jenkins' slave session doesn't inherit the HOSTNAME environment variable.  But the below workaround seems viable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I presume somewhere in your script you have imported the environment system variables by using the following:

```
<property environment="env"/>

...

<condition property="hostname" value="${env.COMPUTERNAME}" else="${env.HOSTNAME}">
   <os family="windows" />
</condition>
```

In this case, `${env.HOSTNAME}` requires a system variable named `HOSTNAME` to be defined on your Linux slave. Apparently it is not.

A better way to do this is through the `hostname` command:

```
<exec executable="hostname" outputproperty="hostname.prop"/>
<echo message="${hostname.prop}" />
```

This should work for *both* Linux and Windows.

Answer (score 1):

```
<exec executable="hostname" outputproperty="my.h.name"/>
<condition property="hostname" value="${env.COMPUTERNAME}" else="${my.h.name}">
    <os family="windows" />
</condition>
```

or:

```
<hostinfo prefix="thisSys"/>
<condition property="hostname" value="${env.COMPUTERNAME}" else="${thisSys.NAME}">
    <os family="windows" />
</condition>
```

refer [HERE](https://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/hostinfo.html) for `<hostinfo>` task.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up resolving this in a slightly different way.

This works on both Windows and Linux and on command line and through Jenkins:

```
<exec executable="hostname" osfamily="unix" failifexecutionfails="false" outputproperty="env.COMPUTERNAME"/>

<echo message="${env.COMPUTERNAME}" />
```

Comment: here, i think, specifying `osfamily` is not necessary. `<exec executable="hostname" outputproperty="hostname.prop"/>` would work for both